# How to get the satellites launched on a certain day

Tags: curated-data, entity

After getting all satellite names using:

```
allSatelliteObjects=SatelliteData[];
```

I see there are a lot of them:

```
allSatelliteObjects//Length
```

42890

If i look at satellites by order using:

```
Entity["Satellite", "25151"]["LaunchDate"]
```

Changing the number 25151 to move around, i see the data is not perfectly ordered by launch date. Is there a way to get the names of the satellites launched on a particular day? I am quite sure there must be a better way then downloading all 42890 entries with there launch date and locally searching them. If wolfram claims that they have actually curated their data how to i get my answer?

Comment: Try `SatelliteData[EntityClass["Satellite", {EntityProperty["Satellite", "LaunchDate"] -> (DateWithinQ[#, DateObject[{1992, 10, 28}]] &)}]]`.

Comment: Thank you your answer works except `DateWithinQ` arguments must be reversed: `DateWithinQ[DateObject[{1992, 10, 28}],#]&`. If you can provide your answer as an answer rather than a comment i am happy to give you credit for it by accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more compact method than the one suggested in comments is to use `EntityClass[]` and `EntityList[]`:

```
CommonName[EntityList[EntityClass["Satellite", "LaunchDate" ->
                                  (DateWithinQ[DateObject[{1992, 10, 28}], #] &)]]]
   {"Galaxy 7", "Ariane 42P+ rocket body", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris",
    "Ariane 42P+ debris", "Ariane 42P+ debris"}
```